# Show small window after button click

Tags: java, dialog, swt

I am looking for a way to display a small window beside a `Button` when it is clicked.
Using a `Jface` `Dialog` is not what I am looking for, but rather a kind of window which can be exactly positioned beside the `Button` like a tool tip.

Comment: 'like' a tooltip or do you need a tooltip? What is it for?

Comment: The purpose is to enter a text after the button is clicked.

Comment: Are you afraid someone might steal your idea? Supply some information. Do you display text in it or should your viewer be able to enter text? What do you have sofar?

Comment: No no there is nothing secret about it :). The button is used to save some data. The user should be able to add a custom text. Like "only testing" or "Final Version". I would like to implement it as a pop up window to save space in the GUI area.

Comment: Did you try `iframe`, display/hide it with `jQuery`? There is a lot of info on those, one example http://www.textfixer.com/html/javascript-pop-up-window.php. Keep in mind people can block pop-ups.

Comment: @RST This is SWT, not something in the browser...

Comment: @Baz my bad, didn't check the tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a second `Shell` and position it just next to the `Button`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Button");

    final Shell popup = new Shell(shell, SWT.NONE);
    popup.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Text input = new Text(popup, SWT.BORDER);

    button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            if(popup != null && !popup.isDisposed())
                popup.close();
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    popup.pack();
    popup.open();

    popup.setLocation(button.toDisplay(button.getBounds().width, 1));

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

---

Of course you'd need to handle resize and move events of your original shell to keep it in place.